# MySQL 5.6 replicate live master WITHOUT down time

Tags: mysql, mysql-replication, mysql5.5

Following the steps to replicate an existing server, it seems most methods rely on the ability to either completely stop the master server or at least prevent it from writing using `flush tables with read lock;` which effectively creates down time as many apps cannot respond properly when unable to write to the database.

Is there a safe way to replicate a master to a slave, ensuring zero down time and complete sync of the database information?

In our scenario we have one master and once slave and they both worked well. A MySQL bug during upgrade from 5.5 to 5.6 got the slave to be slightly out of sync and now we want to re-create its databases completely. For now when we get some sporadic errors we skip them using `STOP SLAVE; SET GLOBAL SQL_SLAVE_SKIP_COUNTER = 1; START SLAVE;` but this only means the replication isn't 100% like the master.

Thanks

Comment: using pt-table-sync may help here

Answer (score 1):

Though it's an old question, but if you still looking for answer - try [percona xtrabackup](https://www.percona.com/software/percona-xtrabackup).
If you have MyISAM tables, use --rsync option. With it we achieved almost seamless dump (lock took around 5-10 seconds for DB around 1Gb).

Answer (score 0):

There is. When all database engines are InnoDB and you have specified the `--single-transaction` switch. This way `flush tables with read lock;` or `--lock-all-tables` isn't needed.

Otherwise, I guess, there are no other options. My condolences.

Basically increasing slave skip counter is bad, unless you're absolutely sure it's safe (for example when replicating missing users `grant` statements or stuff like that).

Comment: All tables are InnoDB but I believe your answer is wrong. Quoting from the manual:" While a --single-transaction dump is in process, to ensure a valid dump file (correct table contents and binary log coordinates), no other connection should use the following statements: ALTER TABLE, CREATE TABLE, DROP TABLE, RENAME TABLE, TRUNCATE TABLE. A consistent read is not isolated from those statements, so use of them on a table to be dumped can cause the SELECT that is performed by mysqldump to retrieve the table contents to obtain incorrect contents or fail."

Comment: Link to the manual entry about it http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/mysqldump.html#option%5Fmysqldump%5Fsingle-transaction

Comment: Just don't use 'em then. Production databases aren't those who got metadata modified often. If yours are - then you're doomed anyway. Use Oracle.

Comment: There's one way though, but it requires zfs. Make a zfs snapshot, make a .cnf fine with `read-only = on` for a snapshot instance, start it, dump it - and restore on a slave. Never used this way myself, but it could work. Last chance to try anyway.

Comment: So let's assume no metadata change is needed. Trying to launch ` mysqldump --all-databases --master-data --single-transaction > all_databases.sql` fails due to `mysqldump: Couldn't execute 'SELECT /*!40001 SQL_NO_CACHE */ * FROM `xxxtable`': The SELECT would examine more than MAX_JOIN_SIZE rows; check your WHERE and use SET SQL_BIG_SELECTS=1 or SET MAX_JOIN_SIZE=# if the SELECT is okay (1104)` but if it wouldn't, you believe the resulting SQL can be loaded into the replication and work perfectly?

Comment: I do. I may be still wrong, but in similar circumstances I'd try this way. If I'm mistaken you will get your errors on the slave in a couple of hours, when the slave will start to diminish the seconds_behind_master delta. Thus, if any logical inconsistencies will happen, they won't happen out of the blue - you will ether see them almost immidiately, or you won't, meaning all is fine.